# yum update fails with lots of duplicate packages

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, rpm

I am trying to update a RHEL server that has not been updated for 4 years. yum update returns a lot of duplicate package errors. I can only paste part of the output. How can I clear these and be able to update the packages?

```
[ec2-user@fileserver]$ sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package NetworkManager.x86_64 1:1.4.0-20.el7_3 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.4.0-20.el7_3 for package: 1:NetworkManager-team-1.4.0-20.el7_3.x86_64
---> Package NetworkManager-ppp.x86_64 1:1.18.8-2.el7_9 will be obsoleting
---> Package audit.x86_64 0:2.6.5-3.el7_3.1 will be updated
---> Package audit.x86_64 0:2.8.5-4.el7 will be an update
---> Package chrony.x86_64 0:2.1.1-4.el7_3 will be updated
---> Package chrony.x86_64 0:3.4-1.el7 will be an update
---> Package cloud-utils-growpart.noarch 0:0.29-1.el7 will be updated
---> Package cloud-utils-growpart.noarch 0:0.29-5.el7 will be an update
---> Package dracut-config-generic.x86_64 0:033-463.el7_3.1 will be updated
---> Package dracut-config-generic.x86_64 0:033-572.el7 will be an update
---> Package dracut-config-rescue.x86_64 0:033-463.el7_3.1 will be updated
---> Package dracut-config-rescue.x86_64 0:033-572.el7 will be an update
---> Package graphviz.x86_64 0:2.30.1-19.el7 will be updated
---> Package graphviz.x86_64 0:2.30.1-22.el7 will be an update
---> Package irqbalance.x86_64 3:1.0.7-6.el7_3.1 will be updated
---> Package irqbalance.x86_64 3:1.0.7-12.el7 will be an update
---> Package kbd.x86_64 0:1.15.5-12.el7 will be updated
---> Package kbd.x86_64 0:1.15.5-15.el7 will be an update
---> Package parted.x86_64 0:3.1-28.el7 will be updated
---> Package parted.x86_64 0:3.1-32.el7 will be an update
---> Package postfix.x86_64 2:2.10.1-6.el7 will be updated
---> Package postfix.x86_64 2:2.10.1-9.el7 will be an update
---> Package rdma.noarch 0:7.3_4.7_rc2-6.el7_3 will be obsoleted
---> Package rdma-core.x86_64 0:22.4-6.el7_9 will be obsoleting
---> Package rh-amazon-rhui-client.noarch 0:2.2.123-2.el7 will be updated
---> Package rh-amazon-rhui-client.noarch 0:3.0.40-1.el7 will be an update
---> Package rhn-check.noarch 0:2.0.2-8.el7 will be updated
---> Package rhn-check.noarch 0:2.0.2-21.el7 will be an update
---> Package rhn-client-tools.noarch 0:2.0.2-8.el7 will be updated
---> Package rhn-client-tools.noarch 0:2.0.2-21.el7 will be an update
---> Package rhn-setup.noarch 0:2.0.2-8.el7 will be updated
---> Package rhn-setup.noarch 0:2.0.2-21.el7 will be an update
---> Package rsync.x86_64 0:3.0.9-17.el7 will be updated
---> Package rsync.x86_64 0:3.1.2-10.el7 will be an update
---> Package subscription-manager.x86_64 0:1.17.15-1.el7 will be updated
---> Package subscription-manager.x86_64 0:1.24.48-1.el7_9 will be an update
Removing NetworkManager.x86_64 1:1.4.0-20.el7_3 - od due to obsoletes from installed 1:NetworkManager-1.18.8-2.el7_9.x86_64
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package NetworkManager.x86_64 1:1.4.0-20.el7_3 will be obsoleted
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:NetworkManager-team-1.4.0-20.el7_3.x86_64 (@rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
           Requires: NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.4.0-20.el7_3
           Removing: 1:NetworkManager-1.4.0-20.el7_3.x86_64 (@rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.4.0-20.el7_3
           Obsoleted By: 1:NetworkManager-ppp-1.18.8-2.el7_9.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               Not found
           Installed: 1:NetworkManager-1.18.8-2.el7_9.x86_64 (installed)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.18.8-2.el7_9
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.1-13.git20140326.4dba720.el7.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-13.git20140326.4dba720.el7
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.1-22.git20140326.4dba720.el7_0.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-22.git20140326.4dba720.el7_0
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.1-23.git20140326.4dba720.el7_0.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-23.git20140326.4dba720.el7_0
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.1-25.git20140326.4dba720.el7_0.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-25.git20140326.4dba720.el7_0
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.1-26.git20140326.4dba720.el7_0.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-26.git20140326.4dba720.el7_0
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.1-28.git20140326.4dba720.el7_0.2.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-28.git20140326.4dba720.el7_0.2
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.1-29.git20140326.4dba720.el7_0.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-29.git20140326.4dba720.el7_0
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.0.0-14.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.0.0-14.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.0.0-16.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7_1.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.0.0-16.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7_1
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.0.6-27.el7.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.0.6-27.el7
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.0.6-29.el7_2.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.0.6-29.el7_2
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.0.6-30.el7_2.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.0.6-30.el7_2
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.0.6-31.el7_2.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.0.6-31.el7_2
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.4.0-12.el7.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.4.0-12.el7
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.4.0-13.el7_3.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.4.0-13.el7_3
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.4.0-14.el7_3.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.4.0-14.el7_3
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.4.0-17.el7_3.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.4.0-17.el7_3
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.4.0-19.el7_3.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.4.0-19.el7_3
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.8.0-9.el7.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0-9.el7
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.8.0-11.el7_4.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0-11.el7_4
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.10.2-13.el7.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.10.2-13.el7
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.10.2-14.el7_5.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.10.2-14.el7_5
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.10.2-16.el7_5.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.10.2-16.el7_5
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.12.0-6.el7.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.12.0-6.el7
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.12.0-7.el7_6.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.12.0-7.el7_6
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.12.0-8.el7_6.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.12.0-8.el7_6
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.12.0-10.el7_6.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.12.0-10.el7_6
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.18.0-5.el7.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.18.0-5.el7
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.18.0-5.el7_7.1.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.18.0-5.el7_7.1
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.18.0-5.el7_7.2.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.18.0-5.el7_7.2
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.18.4-3.el7.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.18.4-3.el7
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-1.18.8-1.el7.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:1.18.8-1.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 292 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
GeoIP-1.5.0-14.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with GeoIP-1.5.0-11.el7.x86_64
1:NetworkManager-1.18.8-2.el7_9.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:NetworkManager-1.4.0-20.el7_3.x86_64
1:NetworkManager-config-server-1.18.8-2.el7_9.noarch is a duplicate with 1:NetworkManager-config-server-1.4.0-20.el7_3.x86_64
1:NetworkManager-libnm-1.18.8-2.el7_9.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:NetworkManager-libnm-1.4.0-20.el7_3.x86_64
1:NetworkManager-team-1.18.8-2.el7_9.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:NetworkManager-team-1.4.0-20.el7_3.x86_64
SDL-1.2.15-17.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with SDL-1.2.15-14.el7.x86_64
acl-2.2.51-15.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with acl-2.2.51-12.el7.x86_64
atk-2.28.1-2.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with atk-2.14.0-1.el7.x86_64
audit-libs-2.8.5-4.el7.i686 is a duplicate with audit-libs-2.6.5-3.el7_3.1.x86_64
audit-libs-python-2.8.5-4.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with audit-libs-python-2.6.5-3.el7_3.1.x86_64
avahi-libs-0.6.31-20.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with avahi-libs-0.6.31-17.el7.x86_64
bash-4.2.46-34.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with bash-4.2.46-21.el7_3.x86_64
32:bind-libs-lite-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.5.x86_64 is a duplicate with 32:bind-libs-lite-9.9.4-38.el7_3.3.x86_64
32:bind-license-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.5.noarch is a duplicate with 32:bind-license-9.9.4-38.el7_3.3.noarch
binutils-2.27-44.base.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with binutils-2.25.1-22.base.el7.x86_64
btrfs-progs-4.9.1-1.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with btrfs-progs-4.4.1-1.el7.x86_64
ca-certificates-2020.2.41-70.0.el7_8.noarch is a duplicate with ca-certificates-2017.2.14-70.1.el7_3.noarch
cairo-1.15.12-4.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with cairo-1.14.2-1.el7.x86_64
checkpolicy-2.5-8.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with checkpolicy-2.5-4.el7.x86_64
chkconfig-1.7.6-1.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with chkconfig-1.7.2-1.el7.x86_64
cloud-init-19.4-7.el7_9.5.x86_64 is a duplicate with cloud-init-0.7.9-3.el7.x86_64
coreutils-8.22-24.el7_9.2.x86_64 is a duplicate with coreutils-8.22-18.el7.x86_64
cpio-2.11-28.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with cpio-2.11-24.el7.x86_64
cronie-1.4.11-23.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with cronie-1.4.11-14.el7_2.1.x86_64
cronie-anacron-1.4.11-23.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with cronie-anacron-1.4.11-14.el7_2.1.x86_64
cryptsetup-libs-2.0.3-6.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with cryptsetup-libs-1.7.2-1.el7.x86_64
1:cups-libs-1.6.3-51.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:cups-libs-1.6.3-26.el7.x86_64
curl-7.29.0-59.el7_9.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with curl-7.29.0-35.el7.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.26-23.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.26-20.el7_2.x86_64
1:dbus-1.10.24-15.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:dbus-1.6.12-17.el7.x86_64
1:dbus-libs-1.10.24-15.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:dbus-libs-1.6.12-17.el7.x86_64
desktop-file-utils-0.23-2.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with desktop-file-utils-0.22-1.el7.x86_64
7:device-mapper-1.02.170-6.el7_9.5.x86_64 is a duplicate with 7:device-mapper-1.02.135-1.el7_3.4.x86_64
7:device-mapper-libs-1.02.170-6.el7_9.5.x86_64 is a duplicate with 7:device-mapper-libs-1.02.135-1.el7_3.4.x86_64
12:dhclient-4.2.5-83.el7_9.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 12:dhclient-4.2.5-47.el7.x86_64
12:dhcp-common-4.2.5-83.el7_9.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 12:dhcp-common-4.2.5-47.el7.x86_64
12:dhcp-libs-4.2.5-83.el7_9.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 12:dhcp-libs-4.2.5-47.el7.x86_64
diffutils-3.3-5.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with diffutils-3.3-4.el7.x86_64
1:dmidecode-3.2-5.el7_9.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:dmidecode-3.0-2.1.el7_3.x86_64
dracut-033-572.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with dracut-033-463.el7_3.1.x86_64
dracut-network-033-572.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with dracut-network-033-463.el7_3.1.x86_64
e2fsprogs-1.42.9-19.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with e2fsprogs-1.42.9-9.el7.x86_64
e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.9-19.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.9-9.el7.x86_64
elfutils-libelf-0.176-5.el7.i686 is a duplicate with elfutils-libelf-0.166-2.el7.x86_64
elfutils-libs-0.176-5.el7.i686 is a duplicate with elfutils-libs-0.166-2.el7.x86_64
1:emacs-filesystem-24.3-23.el7.noarch is a duplicate with 1:emacs-filesystem-24.3-19.el7_3.noarch
epel-release-7-13.noarch is a duplicate with epel-release-7-9.noarch
2:ethtool-4.8-10.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with 2:ethtool-4.5-3.el7.x86_64
expat-2.1.0-12.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.x86_64
file-5.11-37.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with file-5.11-33.el7.x86_64
file-libs-5.11-37.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with file-libs-5.11-33.el7.x86_64
filesystem-3.2-25.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with filesystem-3.2-21.el7.x86_64
1:findutils-4.5.11-6.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:findutils-4.5.11-5.el7.x86_64
fipscheck-1.4.1-6.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with fipscheck-1.4.1-5.el7.x86_64
fipscheck-lib-1.4.1-6.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with fipscheck-lib-1.4.1-5.el7.x86_64
fontconfig-2.13.0-4.3.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with fontconfig-2.10.95-10.el7.x86_64
freetype-2.8-14.el7_9.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with freetype-2.4.11-12.el7.x86_64
gawk-4.0.2-4.el7_3.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with gawk-4.0.2-4.el7.x86_64
gd-2.0.35-27.el7_9.x86_64 is a duplicate with gd-2.0.35-26.el7.x86_64
gdisk-0.8.10-3.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with gdisk-0.8.6-5.el7.x86_64
gdk-pixbuf2-2.36.12-3.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with gdk-pixbuf2-2.31.6-3.el7.x86_64
geoipupdate-2.5.0-1.el7.x86_64 has installed conflicts GeoIP <= ('0', '1.5.0', '13'): GeoIP-1.5.0-11.el7.x86_64
gettext-0.19.8.1-3.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with gettext-0.18.2.1-4.el7.x86_64
gettext-libs-0.19.8.1-3.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with gettext-libs-0.18.2.1-4.el7.x86_64
glib-networking-2.56.1-1.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with glib-networking-2.42.0-1.el7.x86_64
glib2-2.56.1-9.el7_9.x86_64 is a duplicate with glib2-2.46.2-4.el7.x86_64
glibc-2.17-324.el7_9.i686 is a duplicate with glibc-2.17-157.el7_3.2.x86_64
glibc-common-2.17-324.el7_9.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-common-2.17-157.el7_3.2.x86_64
1:gmp-6.0.0-15.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:gmp-6.0.0-12.el7_1.x86_64
gnupg2-2.0.22-5.el7_5.x86_64 is a duplicate with gnupg2-2.0.22-4.el7.x86_64
gnutls-3.3.29-9.el7_6.x86_64 is a duplicate with gnutls-3.3.24-1.el7.x86_64
gobject-introspection-1.56.1-1.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with gobject-introspection-1.42.0-1.el7.x86_64
graphite2-1.3.10-1.el7_3.x86_64 is a duplicate with graphite2-1.3.6-1.el7_2.x86_64
grep-2.20-3.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with grep-2.20-2.el7.x86_64
1:grub2-tools-2.02-0.87.el7_9.6.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:grub2-tools-2.02-0.44.el7.x86_64
grubby-8.28-26.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with grubby-8.28-21.el7_3.x86_64
gsettings-desktop-schemas-3.28.0-3.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with gsettings-desktop-schemas-3.14.2-1.el7.x86_64
gtk-update-icon-cache-3.22.30-6.el7.x86_64 has installed conflicts gtk2 < ('0', '2.24.29', None): gtk2-2.24.28-8.el7.x86_64
gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with gtk2-2.24.28-8.el7.x86_64
gzip-1.5-10.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with gzip-1.5-8.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that someone interrupted yum in the middle of a transaction and yum did not remove the old packages after installing the new version.

See `yum history` what happened in past. You can either try to finish the transaction. Or manually remove the duplicated packages - `rpm -qa |sort` is your best friend.